# Mock part of method in PHP Unit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

How to stub db query result in PHP Unit for the function below?

```
     public function getName($id){
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
        $result = $db->query("SELECT firstname FROM employees WHERE id=" . $id ."limit 1");

        $greeting = 'Hello, my name is' . $result[0];
        return $greeting;
    }
```

Comment: You're going to find mocking a *lot* more difficult if your depencies are being created within methods rather than being injected. Do you have to option of refactoring the class under test?

Comment: @iainn I am ready to consider all options, including refactoring :) Trying to understand best practices in unit testing.

Comment: You should read up on [dependency injection](https://codeburst.io/writing-php-unit-testing-friendly-code-5ef9a8a49da1). The general point is that a class shouldn't ever be responsible for constructing its own dependencies; instead they should be passed in (either in the constructor or to the method itself).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Dependency injection` as good answer. But you could even mock `Mysqli` in your test. Insert code below in you php test class and at runtime it will replace `mysqli` and function `query` by definition below.

```
namespace Name\Space\Of\Your\Php\File\To\Test {
    class mysqli {
        function query(): string
        {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```